# Can I convert a certain string upon reading with fread in R data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to use R's `data.table` package to read a large data set (~800k rows). The set contains results from a simulation of 1000 scenarios (+ a scenario "0" - so 1,001 scenarios in total) and one of the columns, "ScenId", contains the number of the scenario, e.g. 0,1,2,..

The problem is the program used to output this txt file cannot name scenario 1000 as '1000', but uses 'AAA' instead. The column 'ScenId' thus contains only numbers, apart from the value 'AAA'.

I am trying to find a solution to convert 'AAA' to 1000 preferably within the `fread` command.

My current workaround is using `na.strings = "AAA"` in `fread` and then replacing the NA's with 1000, after reading is complete. This works well because those are the only NA instances in the data set.

However, I was hoping for a quicker / more elegant solution, i.e. to do this within the fread command.

Any help / advice will be much appreciated.

Later edit: an attempt at posting sample data.

```
  structure(list(ScenId = "AAA", SensId = "_", SystemProd = "ZCPP__", 
AssumClass = "SPLPSV", ProjPer = 40L, ProjMode = "Annual", 
VarName = "belLUL", Description = "(BEL)", 
Module = "MLIAB", FormType = "inv", Group = "calc.BEL", Width = 12L, 
Decimals = 2L, Scale = "Yes", Value000 = 0, Value001 = 0, 
Value002 = 0, Value003 = 0, Value004 = 0, Value005 = 0, Value006 = 0, 
Value007 = 0, Value008 = 0, Value009 = 0, Value010 = 0, Value011 = 0, 
Value012 = 0, Value013 = 0, Value014 = 0, Value015 = 0, Value016 = 0, 
Value017 = 0, Value018 = 0, Value019 = 0, Value020 = 0, Value021 = 0, 
Value022 = 0, Value023 = 0, Value024 = 0, Value025 = 0, Value026 = 0, 
Value027 = 0, Value028 = 0, Value029 = 0, Value030 = 0, Value031 = 0, 
Value032 = 0, Value033 = 0, Value034 = 0, Value035 = 0, Value036 = 0, 
Value037 = 0, Value038 = 0, Value039 = 0, Value040 = 0), .Names =("ScenId", 
"SensId", "SystemProd", "AssumClass", "ProjPer", "ProjMode", 
"VarName", "Description", "Module", "FormType", "Group", "Width", 
"Decimals", "Scale", "Value000", "Value001", "Value002", "Value003", 
"Value004", "Value005", "Value006", "Value007", "Value008", "Value009", 
"Value010", "Value011", "Value012", "Value013", "Value014", "Value015", 
"Value016", "Value017", "Value018", "Value019", "Value020", "Value021", 
"Value022", "Value023", "Value024", "Value025", "Value026", "Value027", 
"Value028", "Value029", "Value030", "Value031", "Value032", "Value033", 
"Value034", "Value035", "Value036", "Value037", "Value038", "Value039", 
"Value040"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000310788>)
```

This is just one line of my data set. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: A note anticipating potential comments - there is no hope to work at the cause of this issue: there is no way to make the program generating the txt file to print '1000' instead of 'AAA'

Comment: I find this description very confusing. Can you make up a small example?

Comment: Do you have `awk` or `sed` on your system? I'd probably simply do `DT <- fread(...); DT[ScenId == "AAA", ScenId := 1000]; DT[, ScenId := as.integer(ScenId)]`.

Comment: I'm with docendo. what does the file from scenario 999 look like?

Comment: docendo discimus - let me try to re-formulate: I have a data txt file which has 780780 rows and 55 columns. The data pertains to a financial simulation having 1000 scenarios. The first column, "ScenId", contains the number of the correspondent scenario. However, for scenario 1000, the value of ScenID is the string "AAA", for reasons not worth going into. I want to force fread to convert any "AAA" to 1000 upon reading the file. Hope that makes sense !

Comment: Roland: I do not know what awk or sed are, but I will look it up and try your solution. Thank you !

Comment: MichaelChirico, I'm not sure I get your question. There are 780780 lines and 1001 scenarios, so 780 lines of data for each scenario. The first column, with the header "ScenID", contains the number of the respective scenario. i.e. for scenario 999 it's 999. But for scenario 1000 it's AAA - it is the only one odd out.

Comment: To make it more clear, my suggestion doesn't require these tools. But you need one of them or something like them to do it within `fread`. My suggestion is simpler than these tools if you don't know them and also very efficient.

Comment: If all you want to do is change `AAA` to `1000`, then I'm with Roland - just change it after reading the file with `fread`. If you need to change several scenario descriptions, I'd use a lookup table after reading the data.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the suggestions.
In that case I might as well stick to my solution of converting the 'AAA's to NA within fread and then changing all the NAs after reading.
If I don't change the 'AAA' to NA within fread, the other numbers get interpreted as characters and then I would have to re-change that back to numbers + a whole set of other problems appear.

Comment: Honestly I think your present workflow is optimal.